# Confusing power level multiplier

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Power levels are so confusing throughout the DBZ series.

For example:

Kaioken = x2 base
Kaioken x3 = x3 base
Kaioken x4 = x4 base

and so on...

SSJ = x50 base
SSJ Grade 2 = ?
SSJ Grade 3 = ?
SSJ2 = x100 base
SSJ3 = x400 base
SSJ4 = ?
SSJG = ?
SSJGSSJ = ?
LSSJ = ?

Fusion = ?
Fusion Dance = ?
Potara Fusion = ?

Frieza form 1 = 1x base
Frieza form 2 = ?
Frieza form 3 = ?
Frieza form final (full power) = ?
Future Frieza = ? (Same with final form?)
Golden Frieza = ?

Super Buu's Absorption = ? (times the victim's power level)

The unknown factor (*"?"*) makes me confuse about their power levels. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_power_levels) wikia page summarizes the known power levels from the original Dragon Ball series up to Dragon Ball GT. According to the wikia page:

> All of the levels on this list are taken from the manga, anime, movies, movie pamphlets, Daizenshuu guides, video games and stated mathematical calculations. After the Frieza Saga, the only power level stated by a scouter in the series is that of Future Trunks. In the 2000s, V-Jump revealed the official power levels of Cooler in his Final Form, Broly in his Legendary Super Saiyan form, and Gogeta in his Super Saiyan form.

Therefore, we only have the power levels up to SSJ1, with the exceptions listed above.

The concept of numbered power levels was introduced in the Saiyan Saga. My theory is that Akira Toriyama quickly realised that this was a dangerous path: it is not easy to keep the same consistency throughout the series, especially when we know how forgetful the author can be. After the Frieza saga, no additional power levels were introduced. I will be very surprised if they make a come back in Dragon Ball Super.

Comment: That list is wrong during the Frieza Saga. Toyaiama himself listed SS goku at 18,000,000 and Frieza at 15,000,000....up to that point-it was doing ok....then it turned wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some new information, Vados mentioned in Dragon Ball Super, the potara fusion turns the fused fighter created "tens of times" stronger than the original fighters. I couldnt find a video to show it to you, but you can see in Google many users in different websites commenting on this

[fusion tens of times dragon ball vados](https://www.google.com/search?q=fusion%20tens%20of%20times%20dragon%20ball%20vados%20&biw=1366&bih=657&ei=lODxYfb4Ap3A5OUP9aeSiAQ&ved=0ahUKEwj2kqyI0ND1AhUdILkGHfWTBEEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=fusion%20tens%20of%20times%20dragon%20ball%20vados%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwghEAoQoAE6BAghEBU6BQghEKABSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUJoEWMgLYNQNaAFwAngAgAHGAYgB8QWSAQM0LjOYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

According to the Dragon Ball wikia, in Dragon Ball GT the metamor fusion (the other fusion) also turns the fighter ten of times stronger

[Gogeta](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Gogeta)