# Is super saiyan blue supposed to be 50 times stronger than super saiyan god?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Super Saiyan Blue or Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan is said to be obtained by getting the god ki of a super saiyan god and then transforming into super saiyan.

The multiplier for a super saiyan is x50, if super saiyan blue is when you get the god ki of a super saiyan god and then transforming into super saiyan does this mean the power of a super saiyan blue is super saiyan god multiplied by 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at this time there has been no official statement from anyone who matters describing which form is more powerful. The only statement we have was from Akira Toriyama about a year before the blue form was even known about in which he states this:

> **“Simply put, it’s because [the red hair] looks so strong,”** said Toriyama. **“The color yellow has already been used, and blue isn’t really that strong looking, so visually, red is easy to understand.”**
>   
> Source: [kotaku](http://kotaku.com/its-official-goku-has-blue-hair-in-dragon-ball-z-1696943056)

But according to the [wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Blue#Usage_and_power):

> The form, due to the intense training and calm mind needed to acquire it, exceedingly surpasses its predecessor Super Saiyan God, and all of the other Saiyan forms. Despite the form's huge upgrade in power from the original Super Saiyan God, even after training with Whis neither Goku nor Vegeta could challenge Beerus alone.

In Battle of Gods, Whis said that Beerus used 70% of his power while fighting SSG Goku. If SSB was 50x stronger than SSG, it might be very likely that either SSB Goku or Vegeta could defeat Beerus alone given that the 70% thing.

Comment: See related post: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/confusing-power-level-multiplier/28713#28713
Basically, the power levels are not so rigorous in dragon ball super as they were in dragon ball Z.

Comment: I dont think the power levels were rigorous in Dragon Ball Z either. For example Tien was weaker than Vegeta who was weaker than Piccolo (right after he fused) who was a match for 17, who was weaker than Cell first form who was weaker than Cell 2nd form. But Tien was able to hold Cell 2nd form and Piccolo was almost killed by Cell first form and when Vegeta at first couldnt fight 18. Or Vegita sometimes gets zenkais of 50% of his power and other times he gets zenkais of several multiplies even when he got less damage

Comment: @solalito Well, the power level thing is to make the power comparison among the characters easier. Sometimes it would be complicated and confused when applying false information made up by the fans, but overall it's just things DBZ fans like to do in free time.

Comment: @Pablo Tien isn't a very good example as he only held Cell for a few minutes, with his most powerful technique which in the end left him pretty much dead. In DBZ, the powers were more rigorous that we never saw a weaker fighter stand his ground for long against someone much stronger. This is clearly not so much the case in dragon ball super. (Trunks, Master Roshi vs. Frieza's soldiers, etc...)

Comment: @HappyFace Power levels in DBZ were actually issued by Jump magasines and other official material. See http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_power_levels